# Change row.names into column

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got this data.frame of daily stock data.

```
require(quantmod)

BRCM <- as.data.frame(getSymbols.yahoo("BRCM", from="2000-01-01", verbose=F, auto.assign=F))
```

All I want is a column called DATE which looks exactly the same as row.names

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `row.names` function

```
BRCM$DATE<-row.names(BRCM)
```